# Class Not Found using PSR-4

Tags: php, autoloader, psr-4

I have a PSR-4 specification in my composer.json file as below

```
"autoload" : {
    "psr-4" : {
        "MyMVC\\" : "app/"
    }
},
```

[image]

Above is my directory structure. In my Core/Config.php file i have class Config that is under namespace `MyMVC\Core`. (Just taking Config class as example in question, this is same for all classes).

Now in my Config/config.php file i am using below code

```
<?php
use MyMVC\Core;

Config::$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/mymvc';
```

But this gives me error of Class Config Not Found. The problem can be fixed if i use `MyMVC\Core\Config;`. But it should work without using Config explicitly. Since there can be files added by the framework user which are supposed to be autoloaded.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The `use` primitive imports or aliases a namespace or class. As the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php) states:

> PHP supports three kinds of aliasing or importing: aliasing a class name, aliasing an interface name, and aliasing a namespace name. PHP 5.6+ also allows aliasing or importing function and constant names.

Your `use` statement is "aliasing a namespace". So

```
use MyMVC\Core;
```

Is the same as:

```
use MyMVC\Core as Core;
```

Thus in your code:

```
Config::$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/mymvc';
```

Should be:

```
Core\Config::$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/mymvc';
```